# NGINX Reverse proxy for multiple nextjs application error net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: docker, nginx, next.js

I am new to NGINX and implementing reverse proxy. I have two nextjs applications. Both are containerized and both are working fine in their containers. When I implement proxy_pass the second application doesn't work as expected.

App1
works perfectly on location /

App2
returning an error of static files on location /admin

When I go to /admin, it looks like it is looking for nextjs static files on / instead of /admin.

my location configuration is:

```
    location /admin {
        proxy_pass http://adminui:3010; 

    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontendui:3003; //this works fine
    }
```

the /admin location is looking for resources on localhost only whereas it should look for localhost/admin/ as shown below in the picture:

[image]

Looking forward to your guidance.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that all static files from the `/admin` app have URLs that don't start with `/admin` and will then look into the other container.

I think the easiest way would be to define the admin app with a base path. In the `adminui` app. Change the `next.config.js` to include

```
module.exports = {
  basePath: '/admin',
  assetPrefix: '/admin',
}
```

then change the nginx configuration to map to admin path like:

```
    location /admin {
        proxy_pass http://adminui:3010/admin; 
    }
```

That should trigger the static request with `/admin/_next/...` and answer them correctly.

I think it might work with just adding the `assetPrefix` in your setup but it wouldn't work locally.

Comment: I tried this solution but it is returning 502 error.

Comment: Can you share one of the request/response from your browser for this case? Also tell me if it worked locally as expected?

Comment: finally it worked but routing is not working now. instead of going to admin/login, it is going back to localhost/login.

Comment: i added the router.basePath to all urls and it worked. Thanks